# Jquery disable double click when hovering over selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, mouseevent, double-click

I have a function when a user double clicks a horizontal list, that element is moved to another div.  One of the li tags in this unordered list is a text input field.  I would like to disable the double click behavior on that particular field only.  Since the input field is part of the ul element,  I can't seem to find a way to prevent the double click event from firing when that text box is double clicked.  Here's what I have. I accept answers in coffeescript or regular javascript thanks to js2coffee.org :)

The following code moves a horizontal ul element to another div and back to the original if double clicked twice.  Works great.  How can I temporarily disable it when hovering over the input field.

```
$(".available_product_shipments").on "dblclick", ".product", ->
  $(this).appendTo ".product_shipments"
$(".product_shipments").on "dblclick", ".product", ->
  $(this).appendTo ".available_product_shipments"
```

And the JS equivalent:

```
$(".available_product_shipments").on("dblclick", ".product", function() {
  $(this).appendTo(".product_shipments");
});

$(".product_shipments").on("dblclick", ".product", function() {
  $(this).appendTo(".available_product_shipments");
});
```

The html is structured like this

```
<ul>
  <li class="product">
    <ul>
      <li class="avail_qty_field"><input type="text /></li> #Prevent dblclick here
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <ul>
      <li class="avail_qty_field"><input type="text /></li> #Prevent dblclick here
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't know how to do it in coffee script, but you just need to do `if ($(event.target).is("input")) return;` or something similar.

Comment: @KevinB: Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do it in coffee script, but you just need to do

```
if ($(event.target).is("input")) return;
```

or something similar.

This is the non-coffescript version:

```
$(".available_product_shipments").on("dblclick", ".product", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is("input")) return;
  $(this).appendTo(".product_shipments");
});

$(".product_shipments").on("dblclick", ".product", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is("input")) return;
  $(this).appendTo(".available_product_shipments");
});
```

And this is what it looks like in coffeescript

```
$(".available_product_shipments").on "dblclick", ".product", (e) ->
  return  if $(e.target).is("input")
  $(this).appendTo ".product_shipments"

$(".product_shipments").on "dblclick", ".product", (e) ->
  return  if $(e.target).is("input")
  $(this).appendTo ".available_product_shipments"
```

Comment: Since you answered first I gave you credit.  Not sure why stack overflow put your answer at the bottom.

Comment: It's at the bottom because it makes more sense to show the most recent answer first, otherwise you may not notice new answers or modified answers. You can change that by clicking "Oldest" rather than "Active" at the top.

Comment: @ctilley79 Out of curiosity, how would you add the `e` argument to the anonymous function using coffeescript?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(".available_product_shipments").on("dblclick", ".product", function(e) {
  if( $(e.target.localName === 'input')) return;
  $(this).appendTo(".product_shipments");
});

$(".product_shipments").on("dblclick", ".product", function(e) {
  if( $(e.target.localName === 'input')) return;
  $(this).appendTo(".available_product_shipments");
});
```

edit:corrected syntax

Answer (score 0):

Rather than filtering the event after it happens, I would filter it out using the "[not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)" filter. From the example below, I'm not hooking an event on the input type of "text", but am on the type of "password".

**HTML**

```
<div class="collection">
    <input class="product" type="text" />
    <input class="product" type="password" />
</div>
```

**Coffee**

```
$(".collection").on "dblclick", ".product:not('input[type=text]')", ->
  alert "double clicked"
```

**JsFiddle**
See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/anAgent/wQsss/